# From $\phi'(0)=ia$, how $\phi \left(\frac{t}{n}\right)^n\rightarrow e^{iat}$?

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

> From $\phi'(0)=ia$, how can we get that $$\phi
>  \left(\frac{t}{n}\right)^n\rightarrow e^{iat}$$, where $\phi$ is the characteristic function of a random variable $X$?

I know there is an approximation which is $\phi(t)=1+itEX+o({t^{2}})$. But I can't get farther to the answer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For large $n$, $t/n$ is small, so we take a Taylor series of $\phi$ around zero:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\,\phi\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)^n
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\,{\left[\phi\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)\right]}^n\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\,{\left[\phi(0) \;+\; \frac{t}{n}\phi'(0) + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right]}^n\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\,{\left[1 \;+\; \frac{t}{n}\, i a\right]}^n\\
&= e^{i a t}
\end{align}

Here we have used the fact that $\phi(0) = 1$ for any characteristic function, and the fact that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\,{\left(1 \;+\; \frac{z}{n}\right)}^n = e^z$.

Comment: Note that the implicit assumption of $C^2$ wasn't necessary, $o(1/n)$ would've been plenty.